# React app can't receive large response from axios call

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, nestjs

I have react frontend app with Node.js (NestJS) backend. In one of API calls a lot of complicated calculations are made on backend and API return large dataset. Exact size of that data depends on input size, but when I try to receive two 3D arrays of size 4227x3871x2 I can't do that - browser wait 2 or 3 minutes (after server log about ending calculations and sendning data to client) and then error "Out of memory" show up (Google Chrome browser).

Is it possible to receive large data response from backend? And if it's possible - how can I do that?

Here's my axios call, just ordinary request with some data and then console.log() that doesn't show up because browser show "Out of memory" error. But you don't have to care about code because everything is right when I send smaller data, so code works fine - the only issue is how to receive large data from backend in react app after axios call.

```js
const matching = (jobId, priorities, correlationMatrix,
                  dataFile, relationFile, dataDelimiter, relationDelimiter,
                  indexesOfCorrelatedRows, overrideAllRows,
                  avoidOverrideForManuallyCorrelatedRows,
                  manuallyCorrelatedRows, userId, matchType, relationTestRow = -1) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            Authorization: getAuthHeader()
        }
    }

    formData.append('jobId', jobId);
    formData.append('dataFileDelimiter', dataDelimiter);
    formData.append('relationFileDelimiter', relationDelimiter);
    formData.append('correlationMatrix', correlationMatrix);
    formData.append('priorities', JSON.stringify(priorities));
    formData.append('indexesOfCorrelatedRows', JSON.stringify(indexesOfCorrelatedRows));
    formData.append('overrideAllRows', overrideAllRows);
    formData.append('avoidOverrideForManuallyCorrelatedRows', avoidOverrideForManuallyCorrelatedRows);
    formData.append('manuallyCorrelatedRows', manuallyCorrelatedRows);
    formData.append('userId', userId);
    formData.append('matchType', matchType);
    formData.append('relationTestRow', relationTestRow.toString());

    if(typeof dataFile === 'string') {
        formData.append('dataFilePath', dataFile.replace(settings.API_URL, '.'));
    }
    else {
        formData.append('files', dataFile);
    }

    if(typeof relationFile === 'string') {
        formData.append('relationFilePath', relationFile.replace(settings.API_URL, '.'));
    }
    else {
        formData.append('files', relationFile);
    }

    return axios.post(`/correlate`, formData, config);
}

    matching(jobIdTmp, priorities, correlationMatrix,
                dataFile, relationFile,
                dataDelimiter, relationDelimiter,
                overrideAllRows ? (avoidOverrideForManuallyCorrelatedRows ? manuallyCorrelatedRows : []) : indexesOfCorrelatedRows,
                overrideAllRows, avoidOverrideForManuallyCorrelatedRows,
                manuallyCorrelatedRows, matchType)
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
```

Comment: Instead of making one request with a huge result set, you can make several requests that each return a smaller result set. But the details depend on how your data are structured and also what the client wants to do with them. You cannot expect the client to hold more data than fits into its memory.